# How do you properly setup scheduled job for report mailings?

Tags: reports, scheduled-job

Our cron is setup correctly - however I am not sure our parameters for the job `mail_report` are.

`instanceId=[82] format=[print]`

Also, do I have to create a separate job for each report or can I create one job for all reports? Lets say I just want an HTML print out embedded in the body of the email for all reports in which there is an email  setup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format is

```
instanceId=1
format=csv
```

No brackets. The `format` parameter value can also be `print` for printer-friendly HTML. If no format is specified it will send as PDF.

If you are doing this in the UI, you have to setup a separate job for each report. That is useful, because you may want some reports mailing at a different frequency.

Answer (score 1):

The last time I did this, which was a while ago, I didn't do anything with the job in the admin screens in civi, I just set up a cron job and gave it the parameters there, e.g.

`php bin/cli.php -u cms_user_name -e Job -a mail_report --instanceId=82 --format=csv`

So for multiple reports just add more similar lines in your cron script.